# is it possible to Insert a python tuple in a postgresql database

Tags: python, database, postgresql

is it possible to Insert a python tuple  in a postgresql database

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. Probably the easiest way is to serialise it using e.g. [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html), [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) or [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and store it in a `text` field.

Another approach is to use Postgres' multitude of [data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype.html) e.g. [array type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/arrays.html).

Finally, if the number of elements and their types of each tuple is fixed, then you may just create this many columns and map each element to table column.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, PostgreSQL supports array as column type.

```
CREATE TABLE tuples_table (
   tuple_of_strings text[],
   tuple_of_ints    integer[]
);
```

Then inserting is done like this:

```
INSERT INTO tuples_table VALUES (
('{"a","b","c"}', '{1,2}'), 
('{"e",'f... etc"}', '{3,4,5}')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Really we need more information. What data is **inside** the tuple? Is it just integers? Just strings? Is it megabytes of images?

If you had a Python tuple like `(4,6,2,"Hello",7)` you could insert **the string** `'(4,6,2,"Hello",7)'` into a Postgres database, but that's probably not the answer you're looking for.

You really need to figure out what data you're really trying to store before you can figure out how/where to store it.

---

**EDIT:** So the short answer is "no", you cannot store an ***arbitrary*** Python tuple in a postgres database, but there's probably some way to take whatever is *inside* the tuple and store it somewhere useful.

Answer (score 1):

This question does not make any sense. You can insert using SQL whatever is supported by your database model. If you need a fancy mapper: look at an ORM like SQLAlchemy.